# Add / Update / Find .bashrc or .bash_profile in CentOS 6 for Laravel new command to work

Tags: bash, laravel-5, centos, composer-php, laravel-5.4

currently I am unable to run Laravel new command to create new project.

I get the following error:

```
bash: laravel: Command not found
```

I need to add the path:

```
$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
```

But I have never worked with CentOS, I have done once in Ubuntu but I cant find any article on how to proceed with .bashrc in CentOS.

I did ran this command in Terminal:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Then I tried :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Both of the above command ran and no error was thrown and no output. I am not sure if those command even work for CentOS 6.

I tried : `Laravel new blog` after above steps and same output `Laravel not found`. What am I doing wrong or how do I fix this issue ?

## Updated - File content

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used double-quotes to expand `~` representing the home directory path which obviously won't happen.

POSIX defines [Double-Quotes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_02_03) as:

> Enclosing characters in double-quotes ( "" ) shall preserve the literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the exception of the characters dollar sign, backquote, and backslash

so do either do below without quotes

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

(or) use the environment variable `$HOME` for the same

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Comment: Command not found. I did the first one without quotes. Also I cant check source ~/.bashrc . Do I have to create a file? does the file even exist or not?

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia: Create a file of the named `.bashrc` in home and add the export line and do `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I found the file its located in root folder. How can I add it manually? this is the file contents: # .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
 . /etc/bashrc
fi

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia: Add the line `export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin` as the last line of `.bashrc` and do `source ~/.bashrc`